# static video url for videojs in reactjs is playing but not url coming dynamically from database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

video link is of type mp4, when I mention the static link for the video in source it video plays very well, but when the video link is taken dynamically from the database, video is not playing, react is throwing an error like this...

> VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this media.

can anyone assist me??

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getvideobyid()
}

async getvideobyid() {
    try{
        const response = await 
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/get_videos/2');
        this.setState({
        video_url: response.data.video_list[0].url_for_video 
        })
        }
    catch(error){
            console.log('eror while fetching.....', error)
    }
}

render() {
    const videoJsOptions = {
          width: 720,
          height: 300,
          controls: true,
          sources: [{
               src: this.state.video_url,
               type: 'video/mp4',
               },
            ]
      };
    return (
      <div>
          <VideoPlayer 
          {...videoJsOptions}
          />
      </div>
    )
}



export default class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
    this.player = videojs(this.videoNode, this.props, function 
    onPlayerReady() {
        console.log('onPlayerReady', this)
    });
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.player) {
    this.player.dispose()
}
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (this.player) {
    this.player.src({
    type: 'video/mp4',
    src: newProps.video_url
    });
   } 
}

render() {
    console.log('what render is there in node......', this.props)
        return (
            <div>    
                <div data-vjs-player>
                <video ref={ node => this.videoNode = node } 
                className="video-js">      
                </video>
            </div>
            </div>
            )
      }
}
```

updating with the code.
as u can see, for one source I have given the static link, it is commented now, it is playing but the other source is dynamically coming from DB and I have set state. it is not playing. I want that video to be played when the link is coming from the database.

Comment: Could you provide whole component code? Where do you call 'getvideobyid' method? Where did you get VideoPlayer component?

Comment: What is the initial value of `state.state.video_url`? What is its value when the `state` is updated after the call to `getvideobyid`?

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea to check  than `this.state.video_url` not empty before  component rendering

Comment: i have edited code please can u help???????/

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself,
by setting boolean false for isVideo in state,
and when call Api in componentDidmount, i am setting true for isVideo

```
this.state= {
isVideo : false,
video_url:''
}
```